# How to Activate position listener only when page is shown?

Tags: dart, flutter

On a specific page, into the initState methode i start listening to onLocationChanged, like that :

```
_locationSubscription =
    _locationManager.onLocationChanged.listen((Map<String,double> result) {
      setState(() {
        _currentLocation = result;
      });
    });
```

And when i go to another page, or when the page is hidden, the listener stay actif (i never call "cancel" method...). I haven't find any example to do that.

I juste want to manage properly the start/stop/restart listening in accordance of page life cycle. Can you give me the way to do that as well as it's possible ?

Thank you  in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to know when a route is pushed/poped.

```
class AppLifecycleReactor extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppLifecycleReactor({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppLifecycleReactorState createState() => new _AppLifecycleReactorState();
}

class _AppLifecycleReactorState extends State<AppLifecycleReactor>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  int depth = 0;

  @override
  Future<bool> didPopRoute() async {
    depth--;
    if (depth == 0) {
      // restart listener
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> didPushRoute(String route) async {
    depth++;
    // pause listener
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried ... but I do not receive any calls of type "didPushRoute" or "didPopRoute".. I probably make a mistake somewhere ...

Comment: I succeeded, but with "didChangeAppLifecycleState", like that  `void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {  
    
    switch( state ) {  
      case AppLifecycleState.paused :  
         _locationSubscription.pause();  
        break;  
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed :  
         _locationSubscription.resume();  
        break;  
    }  
  }`  Thank You

Comment: I achieved the same. But the thing with the didPushRoute I wasn't either able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with Firestore database and StreamBuilder and realized that my list view got updates from the database even when it was inactive. Because this causes unneeded data traffic I ended up looking for a solution and using [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) as proposed by [Rémi Rousselet] will not work. The `WidgetBinding` source docs state the following:

> /// Called when the system pops the current route.
>     /// This first notifies the binding observers (using
>     /// [WidgetsBindingObserver.didPopRoute]), in registration order, until one
>     /// returns true,

Also you can see in the implementation:

```
  Future<void> handlePopRoute() async {
    for (WidgetsBindingObserver observer in List<WidgetsBindingObserver>.from(_observers)) {
      if (await observer.didPopRoute())
        return;
    }
    SystemNavigator.pop();
  }
```

That the iteration will run till one of the observers will return true, that means that if there was another observer registered before ours that will return `true`, the `didPushRoute()` and `didPushRoute()` methods in our class will not be executed.
I am still looking for the right solution and will update my answer once I find a good one.

Comment: Hey @Dimitri L. Did you found something about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check `isActive` of the route for the page, you can limit `setState()` to be called only when the page is active:

```
_locationSubscription =
    _locationManager.onLocationChanged.listen((Map<String,double> result) {
      if(myPageRoute.isActive) {
        setState(() {
          _currentLocation = result;
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, it seem to be simple... How you get myPageRoute please ?

Comment: `static const String myPageRoute = '/myPage';` if you define your route paths as constants to avoid inconsistencies if you use it in multiple places.